# cron файл на сервере

Tags: cron, веб-сервер

Раньше этого не делал, но получил тз написать ssh файл (cron), который нужно разместить на сервере, чтобы он каждых два часа останавливал и запускал сервер. Можете кто-то подсказать где почитать или рассказать, как это делать и куда его закидывать?

Comment: А что, не судьба почитать что такое cron и как его использовать? https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: @zed ну я это прочитал. только что-то мало из этого всего понял. как его закинуть на серве, где его размещать, как правильно писать.

Comment: Вы наверное не понимаете сути вашего ТЗ. Судя по всему, вам нужно написать `bash` скрипт, который выполняет полезную работу (перезапуск сервера), залить этот скрипт на сервер и создать задание в `cron` с вызовом вашего скрипта с заданной периодичностью.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сохраняем текущий крон пользователя в текущую директорию:

```
crontab -l > cron.bak
```

Добавляем правило `nano cron.bak`:

```
30 3 * * *  /home/user/bin/backup.sh > /home/user/logs/backup.log 2>&1
```

В `/home/user/logs/backup.log` будут писаться и все ошибки выполнения самого скрипта

Перезаписываем крон для текущего пользователя:

```
crontab cron.bak
```

Более подробно можно почитать [в одном из источников](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/cron)

Comment: а в чем писать этот 'cron' и как его загрузить на сервер и в какую директорию? 
если надо чтобы он просто каждый два часа останавливал и потом опять поднимал сервер. 
пример квайери, которая должна выполняться. 

sudo service tomcat7 stop
sudo service tomcat7 start

Comment: использую putty для подключения к серверу. 
хочу пройти по указану пути к логами, пишет что такой директории нету.
и еще пишет `no crontab for root`

Comment: Это же абстрактные пути, вам нужно заменить на свои.

Comment: Еще по сабжу https://toster.ru/q/195229

Comment: Поправил первую ссылку, сори, не проверил.

Comment: @Минусаторам, вы хоть комментируйте что не так...

Comment: спасибо, я разобрался. остался только последний вопрос. как мне с putty( возможно вы знаете) загрузить шел файл в cron.hourly?

Comment: WinSCP вам в помощь!

Comment: все, спасибо. я просто в середине /etc/cron.hourly тачнул новый sh файл и в той же папке /etc/cron.hourly и изменил через crontab -e. теперь жду или будет работать